# Embedding a SFML window on a web application

Tags: c#, sfml

I am using Otter2D, a C# port of SFML. I want to embed the OpenGL window onto a website. Is this possible?

Comment: @Marvin why do you think more details would help to answer "how to embed C# form/app into web page"? Especially MRE? And how it would change answer from "just no"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Having a little bit more information may make it easier to answer the question

Comment: @Marvin I'm still not sure what kind of details would make answer different than "no"? It is generally better to ask for specific details than just "more details. I.e. for debugging question MRE is required so it's reasonable to ask for one, but for general how-to question one should ask for specific details that are either unclear or allow to narrow down the question. I personally don't see what kind of details would change the questions to have different answer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I guess you’re right, I habe deleted my comment.